# How to fetch data with one to one relationship using laravel+VueJS

Tags: html, laravel, laravel-5, vue.js, vuejs2

How can I show the name of user using a foreign key?
I have 2 tables:
users and departements, one departement have only one cheif and a user can be a cheif of only one departement. So I think it's a "one to one relationship".
the departement table have the"user_id" as a foreign key from the table users.
In the vue I have:

```
<tr v-for="departement in departements" :key="id" >
                <td>{{departement.id }}</td>
                <td>{{departement.name }}</td>
                <td>{{departement.user_id }}</td>
                <td>{{departement.bio }}</td>
```

I want to display the name of the user from users table who has the user_id.
Thank you.

---

Dosen't work
**Department Controller:**

```
public function index()
{
    return Departement::where('name','!=','admin')->latest()->paginate(100);
    $departements = Departement::with('chief')->get();
    return response()->ajax($departements, 200);
}
```

am i right?

Answer (score 1):

You need to define relationships first..

**Department Modal**

```
public function chief()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'user_id');
}
```

now fetch the data with eager loaded department.

**Controller function**

```
$departments = Department::with('cheif')->get();
```

Now you can access particular `Cheif` object in `department` object.

**In Vue**

```
<td>{{ department.cheif.name }}</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Do a get request to get the users

```
mounted () {
  axios.get('some/api/users')
  .then(res => {
    this.$set(this, 'users', this.users.reduce((accum, user) => accum[user.id] = user, {}))
    // transform the JSON to an object that maps to the user id
  })
}
```

2. In your template

```
<tr v-for="departement in departements" :key="id" >
                <td>{{departement.id }}</td>
                <td>{{departement.name }}</td>
                <td>{{departement.user_id }}</td>
                <td>{{departement.bio }}</td>
                <td>{{users[department.user_id].name}}</td>
```

Comment: I got the data of the departments and the chief but it doesn't display . don't know why!

Comment: When i see the data in the console of the navigator I get the data of the department and the user who has the user_id but it has not display on the table